# How to add spaces into a developing variable after making a range function

Tags: python, string, for-loop, printing, user-input

I'm writing a program that asks how many names a user has. Then, using a for loop, I would ask the user for each of their names. And finally, print their full name. All I know is that I should keep a running total of strings and that I can make a string variable to contain the information like `my_string = ""`. That's what I'm having a little trouble with.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to put the spaces in between strings inside a variable as it develops inside the loop. In my code, the names print, but it's all together. So if I typed "John" and "Smith", it would print "JohnSmith" as the `full_name` variable I have. I've already tried adding `""` inside the `full_name` variable which is in the loop, but nothing changed.

```
full_name = ""

names = int(input("How many names do you have?: "))

for i in range(names):
    next_name = input("Name: ")
    full_name = full_name + next_name + ""

print(full_name)
```

I know this is beginner stuff, but I started learning Python like a week ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need, I think.

```py
full_name = ""

names = int(input("How many names do you have?: "))

for i in range(names):
    next_name = input("Name: ")
    full_name = full_name + " " + next_name

print(full_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need `join`
Something like this (`strip` is here to clear input)

```
name_words = [input("Name: ").strip() for _ in range(names)]
print(" ".join(name_words)
```

Comment: I'd say `name_count` would be more expressive, but maybe the quotation of OP's variable will suffice...

Comment: Yes, I don't think `names` is a good name for 'int' variable, but it was that OP used so... :-)

Answer (score 1):

To put a space in between two strings, you can add a space explicitly:

```py
str1, str2 = 'hello', 'world'

print(str1 + ' ' + str2)
```

Though it's better practice to use string formatting:

```py
print('{} {}'.format(str1, str2))

# or f-strings (python 3.5+)
print(f'{str1} {str2}')
```

Last, for dynamic string formatting (you don't know how many arguments you'll get), you can use `str.join`:

```py
print(' '.join((str1, str2)))

# or with something like a list comprehension
choices = [input("Name: ").strip() for _ in range(names)]
print(' '.join(choices))
```

Answer (score 1):

An interesting option would be to let `print` and *unpack* do the formatting work:

```
names = []

count = int(input("How many names do you have?: "))

for i in range(count):
    names.append(input("Name: "))

print(*names)
```

This works because the [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) uses space (`' '`) as the default separator for its arguments whereas the [unpack operator (`*`)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) transforms the list variable into a list of positional arguments.